# What is really inside the browser that makes my system compatible with chrome, opera and safari but not on firefox?

Tags: browser, cross-browser

Sorry i am unable to provide you a fiddle or the url of my working system. I wanted a comprehensive explanation why my system is not compatible(at some functions like caret positioning) with firefox and compatible with the other three? What's inside those system? Is it because the three browsers are webkit-based?

This is a general question. Im not asking how to fix my system to be cross-browser compatible. I wanted to understand why such thing happen, dipper.

Comment: They use different engines. It's impossible to say why your system doesn't work if you can't tell any details.

Comment: @JUhana: Does the 3 browser has the same engine?

Comment: If you find a comprehensive explanation, do share it with us. In fact better still share it with the guys doing the browsers, may be they'll all start rowing the boat in the same direction...

Comment: Oh well that's how long I held my breath waiting for the above. Need to lay off the cigs.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays most cross browser differences is because you are using non-standard functions that are added by one browser vendor, so it's not supported by other browsers. The [W3C organisation](http://www.w3.org/) defines some standards for the web, and that's what browsers try to follow.

Older versions of browsers were not as good at following standards, which is most noticable with older versions of Internet Explorer, especially as they tend to be upgraded less frequently than browsers that people choose to install themselves.